# Can I use runtime permission without minimum SDK check?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I am asking runtime permission for `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` without minimum SDK check. After that, we face application lagging issue in devices below Android 10. Does it cause by not checking minimum SDK before asking for permission?

Comment: No, I guess the lag is not related to that.  Checking min sdk is just a simple operation which doesn't have huge effect on performance

Comment: i did not check minimum SDK before permission.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not related to the permission. But, did you try without asking the permission whether the application lags? And, why skip a simple min SDK condition?

Comment: yes its not lagging without runtime permission.